# How to create a SFTP (SSH) User with extremely limited permissions

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, sftp

i run a server on Ubuntu Server 14.04.
I want to create a user that is able to connect via sftp, download 1 file and terminate the connection.
The user should not be able to do ANYTHING else.
Browsing system files or settings nor command line entries, nothing.
Log in, download the file, gg.
When the file is updated, log in download it, gg.
The file is in the same directory every time and has the same name every time but is updated.

EDIT:
I'm trying to implement your solution but i've found some problems: On the config file of the ssh on my configuration there is a line with "allow groups sshdusers". I've added sftp_users. But there's another problem ahead. sudo chown root.root /ubuntu/ is not optimal for me because root is not able to ssh and write to the directory the file that "ubuntu" has to download (we will call it user1. I want user1 to be able to write on the directory and ubuntu to read only. If i change sudo chown user1.user1 /ubuntu/ and i try to sftp with the user ubuntu the connection fails. If i leave it root as you do i can connect but i can't see the currentdirectory i see only / and empy on filezilla. i've even added user1 to sftp_users, but still no success.

Many thanks

Answer (score 11):

Let's start

Create user `ubuntu`

```
sudo useradd ubuntu
```

Make password

```
sudo passwd ubuntu
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Create for SFTP only group

```
xxx@xxx:~$ sudo groupadd sftp_users
```

Add to a user "ubuntu" for SFTP only group

```
xxx@xxx:~$ sudo usermod -G sftp_users ubuntu
```

Make dir for `sftp` access

```
sudo mkdir /ubuntu
```

Change owner, because read/write permission

```
sudo chown root.root /ubuntu/
```

Add permission

```
sudo chmod 755 /ubuntu/
```

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

`sudo nano  /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment out and add a line like below

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Add at the last

```
Match Group sftp_users
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ChrootDirectory /ubuntu
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Restart `ssh` service

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

With this cenfiguration you can ssh into folder `ubuntu` and get files. Can not `put` or `delete`

Try.

Edit 1

To sftp in right folder edit `/etc/passwd`. Change line for user `ubuntu` to look like this

`sudo nano /etc/passwd`

```
 ubuntu:x:1001:1001::/ubuntu:
```

This will change user ubuntu home folder to your sftp server folder.

> Enabling `root` account is not good idea.

You can ssh to server with `user1`.

If you add user `user1` in `sudoer group` you will be able to write in
folder `/ubuntu/` and set appropriate permission

```
sudo adduser user1 sudo
```

Make folder, write in folder ubuntu. After actions you must set permission for user `ubuntu`. Easiest way is to agai set permission to 755

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /ubuntu/
```

-R - option will give reading permission of all files and dir's for user `ubuntu`

Comment: Many thanks to you. See my edit for more, as the comments are really tight.

Comment: You have Edit 1 in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that it doesn't work. With filezilla sftp i can't write on the folder with user1 nor ubuntu. logging in with ubuntu via sftp gives me the / folder despite the last modifications. i've tried multiple times and i can't figure out the problem.

Comment: I think also that 755 is not good for this purpose because the owner is root and sudoers cannot write in the folder with 755

Comment: Even back in 2015, I'm sure Ubuntu was using `adduser` and `addgroup`, rather than `useradd`, `groupadd`, etc. The `sudo chown root.root /ubuntu/` is just wrong. You created the directory using `sudo`, so the ownership is already `root`. It should use `ubuntu.sftp_users`. Finally, if you'd initially created it as owned by `ubuntu`, everything from "_Enabling root user_…" is superfluous.